# create unpublic project via API in redmine [1.4.4.stable]

Tags: api, project, redmine

I can't find any information about that. I leave it for the generations ;)

Solution:

```
172     custom_json = {
173             "project": {
174                 "name": project.name,
175                 "identifier": identifier,
176                 "parent_id": parent_id,
177                 "description": project.description,
178                 **"is_public": False,**
179                 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
172     custom_json = {
173             "project": {
174                 "name": project.name,
175                 "identifier": identifier,
176                 "parent_id": parent_id,
177                 "description": project.description,
178                 "is_public": False,
179                 }
```